# How to include a query string parameter into the Jenkins-Blitz build step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, blitz++

I am using the Blitz plugin for Jenkins for load testing our API.

I am having trouble parameterizing the domain part of the query string.

What am I doing wrong with how I define and use a SERVER_IP variable, as shown in the below snippet of a Jenkin's job configuration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: ``io.blitz.curl.exception.BlitzException: Can't parse the URL. You sure it's valid?``

Comment: Looks like Jenkins isn't expanding the value of $SERVER_IP.  Try ${SERVER_IP}

Comment: Trying ${SERVER_IP} returns same error, io.blitz.curl.exception.BlitzException: Can't parse the URL. You sure it's valid?